# Hystrix fallback method gives error

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-netflix, hystrix, netflix, circuit-breaker

I am trying to use Netflix Hystrix Fallbackmethod & with a simple spring program. i followed all the basic steps as described in some tutorials, but still I am getting error,

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hystrixCommandAspect' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/netflix/hystrix/HystrixCircuitBreakerConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to inst
```

Anyone know if any configuration is missing? Below is the code snippet.

My Main,

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableCircuitBreaker
public class SpringBootHelloWorldApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootHelloWorldApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

My Controller,

```
@RestController
@Component
public class TestController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/hello", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @HystrixCommand(fallbackMethod="Error")
    public String Hello() {
        String text = "Hi Hello, you have come to correct place";

        //creating an exception to trigger fallBackMethod!!!
         if(text != "something")
            throw new RuntimeException(); 

        return text;
    }

    public String Error() {
        String text = "Error - this is an backup text";

        return text;
    }
}
```

When i run my Main class, I am getting this error,

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hystrixCommandAspect' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/netflix/hystrix/HystrixCircuitBreakerConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.netflix.hystrix.contrib.javanica.aop.aspectj.HystrixCommandAspect]: Factory method 'hystrixCommandAspect' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/aspectj/lang/JoinPoint
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1128) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1023) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:751) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:861) ~[spring-context-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541) ~[spring-context-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:761) [spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:371) [spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) [spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1186) [spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1175) [spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
    at com.siddharth.SpringBootHelloWorldApplication.main(SpringBootHelloWorldApplication.java:14) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.netflix.hystrix.contrib.javanica.aop.aspectj.HystrixCommandAspect]: Factory method 'hystrixCommandAspect' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/aspectj/lang/JoinPoint
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    ... 18 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/aspectj/lang/JoinPoint
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCircuitBreakerConfiguration.hystrixCommandAspect(HystrixCircuitBreakerConfiguration.java:60) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-core-1.2.6.RELEASE.jar:1.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCircuitBreakerConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$8c1f134f.CGLIB$hystrixCommandAspect$2(<generated>) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-core-1.2.6.RELEASE.jar:1.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCircuitBreakerConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$8c1f134f$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$af9d12ee.invoke(<generated>) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-core-1.2.6.RELEASE.jar:1.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228) ~[spring-core-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:356) ~[spring-context-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCircuitBreakerConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$8c1f134f.hystrixCommandAspect(<generated>) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-core-1.2.6.RELEASE.jar:1.2.6.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
    ... 30 common frames omitted
```

My Dependencies,

[image]

Comment: I saw your answers on Hystrix in some posts so, I am tagging you @David

Comment: seems like you're missing apectj

Comment: Well I'm new to spring. I looked up on AOL couldn't get much info.  Please let me know what to add and where.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have somehow solved this issue.
I used AOP Jars in Maven, and it is working fine!!

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score -1):

This error may result from maven dependency conflict.

You'd better use spring-cloud-starter-parent to avoid dependency conflict:

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>Camden.SR7</version> <-- release version -->
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    ...

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-hystrix</artifactId>
        <!--<version>1.3.6.RELEASE</version>--> <-- no need -->
    </dependency>
```